# Keeps saying that Python is not found and that I need to install it on Microsoft even though I got the extensions?

Tags: python, windows

I am very much a new person to coding and I was primarily trying to do something for some browser game I play. This message is what I am most concerned of: "Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases." I've looked at countless videos and articles but cannot find anything that is of use for me. I don't know if this has been an issue for anyone else or has been asked of and I use Python. Could someone please help me? I also use Windows 10 with the newest version possible (3.10.6).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Soiiw.png

Comment: Install Python from http://www.python.org. The MS Store version has all sorts of issues.

Comment: That's the one I have installed but that message keeps popping up.

Comment: When you were installing Python, did you select the option to add Python to your PATH?

Comment: As you are using vscode, have you installed the correct python extensions?

Comment: When I installed it I never selected anything and just kept pressing next, mostly in fear that I would mess up something.

Comment: I watched videos on what to install so I am pretty sure I did it correctly.

Comment: You can check your environment variables by searching for it in windows, then click `environment variables` in the bottom right, look for `path` and if the location of your python install is in there, then you have got it, if not just add it. Just don't delete anything that you haven't typed because it could cause some problems with other path variables.

Comment: Also the extension is `.py` not `.python`.

Comment: Decided to uninstall the entire thing and reinstall it and hopefully it will resolve the issue. How should I set it up?

Comment: Just make sure to select the option to automatically set up your environment variables if there is one, once you have installed go to vscode and install the `python` extension by microsoft. If it still doesn't work try running `py` or `python3` in the terminal. If they don't output something like `the system could not find this command` then at least you know you have got python.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please reinstall the python
[when installing make sure to check **add python 3.10.6(your version) as Path**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gHKR.png)

and in your code you hace to use this code to import emoji library also

```
pip install emoji
```

hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

For me, turning off Python under "Apps > App Execution Aliases" in Windows 11 settings fixed it.

**Fix Python for Stable Diffusion on Windows 11**

[image: Fix Python for Stable Diffusion on Windows 11]